# Trying to learn JSON after a little CSS and HTML

Tags: css, json-ld, responsive-webdesign, learning

I'm learning to place media queries into a website for getting the correct layout changes I need on different mobile devices. I've done this in CSS and Bootstrap before, but my job is asking me to do it in an entirely JSON website.

I found a few different points in the website's style sheets that are formatted like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .productgrid--outer .pagination--container,
  .productgrid--outer .breadcrumbs-container {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Is this media query applying these padding rules to anything using the tags listed in there, like `.productgrid--outer`? If I'm reading this correctly, then I could make media queries using the same formatting for the tags that I need to change then. I think that's what is happening, but I've never poked with JSON before so I wanted to make sure I'm not misreading this.

Comment: What does "entirely JSON website" mean?  I'm not aware of any way to make a website using only JSON.  The code you provided looks like it is CSS not JSON.  Maybe it is using a framework that formats JSON data into templates?

Comment: As an example, the website's asset pages are like this "style.css.liquid" or "Index.json", if that helps with clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure what an "asset page" is.  Do you mean the assets of the page?

Comment: I mean an "asset page" to describe a type of page or sheet that provides styling or scripting for other pages within a website. Examples would commonly be a "style.css" page, a "custom.min" page, or maybe a "template.liquid" page.

Comment: Okay, I would usually use URL for that. A page is something that the user looks at in a web browser.

Comment: What? No. You don't just use an external URL for all your style sheets. That would be crazy. You keep them inside your site's folder structure, and call them into the HTML pages as-needed.

Comment: This doesn't matter anyway, I'm just moving on. All I had asked for was info on if the bit of code I pasted was a JSON media call or not. That's it. All you have done is randomly edit my post without giving a reason, and then nit-pick about word-choice in my question. This was a waste of my time. You clearly have no idea what you're talking about and can't help me anyway. Last time I ever try getting help on this site lol.